# How does a tokend's probe() function work?

Tags: macos, keychain, smartcard, tokend

[SecTokend.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/SecurityTokend/SecurityTokend-55000/lib/SecTokend.h) declares a function

`CSSM_RETURN (*probe)(SecTokendProbeFlags flags, uint32 *score, char tokenUid[TOKEND_MAX_UID]);`

which is called by securityd at some point. But I can't find when and how it is called.
a) On which conditions does tokend call this function?
b) How is probe() supposed to know for which device it has to look?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Tokend is deprecated from Lion onwards.
- Tokend gets a reader name as parameter
- probe is called to test if this tokend can handle the given card (it is supposed to return a score, and the tokend with the best score will win the inserted card)

Comment: Thank you. But when is this function called, what are the "external" conditions? Will it be called periodically or whenever the keychain services are accessed or when a usb/smartcard device is pplugged into the computer or ...? And what will the reader name be? Is it something from a config file or a device path/locationId or ...? And where is this `startupReaderInfo` defined?

Comment: Smart card reader name as present in PC/SC. Like seen with opensc-tool -l. probe() is called when a smart card is inserted to a reader.

Comment: It is called on device insertion, shortly after the Tokend executable is launched. startupReaderInfo is a function pointer that presumably is filled in by some external process.. digging into this, I too would be interested in finding out where this comes from.